# Unable to send api requests from the angular app to the API

Tags: typescript, http, post, asp.net-core, angular7

I am setting up an angular app with angular 7.when i try to send POST request for log  in.No action happen.

My back end is asp.net-core.I have set up the CORS already.

Login.component.ts

```
login() :void {
    if (this.loginForm.valid){
     this.userSrvc.login(this.loginForm.value).subscribe(
       res =>{
        console.log("success");
     },
     error => {
        console.log("login failed");
      }
    });
  }
 }
```

user.service.ts

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.url = AppConstants.API_ENDPOINT;
    this.headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8' });
  }

  login(params: any): Observable<User> {
    console.log("service called");
    const body = JSON.stringify({ UserName: params.userid, Password: params.password });
    console.log("body", body);
    return this.http.post<User>(this.url + 'Login', body, { headers: this.headers });
  }
```

this method should call the API and return a response either success or fail,But no action happened.
Thanks in advance

Comment: How do you know that no action happened? What have you tried? Do you see your console.logs? Have you tried to adding debugger; on the line after console.log("body", body); and then opened developer tools in chrome and refreshed your page? Have you looked on the network tab under developer tools to see if any request was made?

Comment: How are you building the form as reactive or template-driven? Put a console.log inside the conditional when the form is valid to know if the event is triggered or not, if is not triggered follow this https://angular.io/guide/forms-overview to build a properly form.

Comment: I created this snippet https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g56k9t to help you.